# How to encode an array as JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have an array in JavaScript that is `grossIncome`.Tthis array contains 6 elements. Now I want to send this array to an another PHP page using `$.ajax` method but how can I encode this array in JSON format?

Answer (score 3):

Use `JSON.stringify()` (if you want to support older browsers, you have to include  [this file](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) from Douglas Crockford):

```
$.ajax(
{
  "url": "some_script.php",
  "data": {json: JSON.stringify(gossIncome)},
  "success": function()
  {
    // Do something! 
  }
});
```

In a PHP script you could decode it with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
<?php

$json = isset($_GET['json']) ? $_GET['json'] : exit('No JSON passed!');

$array = json_decode($json);

if ( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE )
  exit('JSON invalid!');

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the required JS file - you can find it at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Thanks edited. But actually all modern browsers supports `JSON.stringify()` without any libraries.

Comment: Better: `data: {json: JSON.stringify(gossIncome)}`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like json_encode();

http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457

Answer (score 0):

The array is already technically in `JSON`, though to be passed via `HTTP` to a file, you'll want to serialize the data to maintain the name pair values as a string. Fortunately, `jQuery` has a built-in `param()` method. You could use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $.param(grossIncome),
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg); // or whatever
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, `param()` in only useful for arrays in the form of object maps... ie:

```
var grossIncome = {
    valueOne: "123",
    valueTwo: "321"
};
```

Comment: `grossIncome` seems to be an array, you cannot call `serialize` on it.

Comment: Wow, I muscled with it for a while and you're totally right. I could have swore I've used `serialize()` for this purpose before, but clearly I'm mistaken. Thanks for the catch and I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

If you use jQuery or other JS Frameworks, look at there plugin repositories, normally they have a JSON class to de/encode arrays/objects...